# React Native : persist API data and check if it's up-to-date when connected

Tags: react-native, api

I want to know if there are any strategies (and especially for React-Native apps) to

1. The first time the app is run (or even during installation), make a `GET` call to an API;
2. Store the recieved data (using `AsyncStorage` for example);
3. When the app doesn't have any internet connection, just use the stored data;
4. If however, the device is connected first check if there has been any update to the API data;
5. If so, update the stored data; otherwise just use the stored data.

PS: I need this for a "slow-evolving" data and I want this for two reasons:

1. Allow users to use the app even without internet connection;
2. Avoid multiple "useless" API calls.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).
Call API request once when app is opened.
If there is internet connection it will populate redux state with new data.
Otherwise, the current data from redux state will be displayed.